# Google play and firebase account

Tags: firebase, admob, google-play-console

I am having two different accounts one for google play and one for admob now i want to use firebase with my new project, so in short, i want to know which account should i use with firebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no connection between Firebase and Play in terms of the account you use to manage them.  I'd use the Admob account, because you can [link admob to Firebase](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6383165?hl=en).